# Merrging two data frames containing -/+ signs

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I merged two data tables using R merge() as C=merge(A,B,by="id"); but in my final output (C), the -/+ sign were changed to zeros.
I did not intend the -/+ sign to be altered. Any solution to this problem?

dataframe A:

```
id  V1  V2  V3
A   23  -   23
B   44  -   35
C   13  +   14
D   20  -   12
```

dataframe B:

```
id  X   Y   Z
A   16  -   45
B   26  -   28
C   29  +   44
D   54  -   34
```

Output:

```
id  V1  V2  V3  X   Y   Z
A   23  0   23  16  0   45
B   44  0   35  26  0   28
C   13  0   14  29  0   44
D   20  0   12  54  0   34
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Can you post two sample datasets (using `dput`) that would replicate the problem you're describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it works

```
R> x = data.frame(c(1, 2), c("+", "-"))
R> y = data.frame(id=c(1, 2), sy=c("-", "+"))
R> x = data.frame(id=c(1, 2), sx=c("+", "-"))
R> x
  id sx
1  1  +
2  2  -
R> y
  id sy
1  1  -
2  2  +
R> merge(x, y, by="id")
  id sx sy
1  1  +  -
2  2  -  +
```